# leaflet marker element style not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, maps, leaflet

I try to change marker style by js.

but when I typed this code:

```
let markerElement = marker.getElement();
markerElement.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
```

I have an exeption that said that `markerElement` is undifined.

any help.

(or just a way to rotate the marker by the typescript)

Comment: Can you show it in plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using this package?
https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker

Comment: is this work with ionic 2 ? (angular 2 / typescript)

Comment: @noamaghai there should be no reason why a JS library would not work with TS. You may miss definitions, but you should be able to set an `any` definition in your project.

Comment: I used this from the example:

let marker = L.marker([me.cLocation.lat, me.cLocation.long], {
 icon: this.iconWithVision
 rotationAngle: degrees
})

but I have an error at the compile: 


Argument of type '{ icon: Icon; rotationAngle: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MarkerOptions'.

Comment: I cant use this plugin because that plugin has a bug with the last version of leaflet.

Comment: @noamaghai Please can you be more specific about your last comment "that plugin has a bug with the last version of leaflet"? Looks like the plugin author specifically released version `0.2.0` to ensure compatibility with Leaflet `1.1.0` (see [#13](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker/issues/13)). Result seems good: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/biwo/1/edit?html,output If you can explain the bug, please report an issue on the plugin repo so that people are aware of it.

Comment: that code not solve my problem and i dont know what to do with this problem.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8hkrb_utevUakJoYXZfUTNvUGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @noamaghai you should learn how to use JS libraries in a TS project, and how to silence that message by allowing it in your definitions.

Comment: So someone can show me an ionic 2 example of this plugin ?